# Search based on words of a phrase, just like SO related questions

Tags: java, lucene, morelikethis

I'm trying to get search results just like the stack overflow Related questions, when you ask a new question.

How can I do with lucene, a search which would match all words or at least one or two words in my phrase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) contribution called [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html) that does what you're looking for. Here's an article on using it: [Using Lucene and MoreLikeThis to show related content](http://cephas.net/blog/2006/11/14/using-lucene-and-morelikethis-to-show-related-content/).

Comment: Is there an alternative without MoreLikeThis ?